# Why is $\ddot \theta=0$? - a Kinetics of Particles question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

The question arises from this problem:

> As shown in  Figure 7, a 2m diameter wheel rotates in the horizontal plane at a 
>   constant angular velocity ω= 7 rad/s.  A 180g mass slides, without friction, along one of its spokes. The speed of the mass, relative to the spoke, is 20 m/s when its position r = 0.15m. Calculate the speed of the mass (relative to the spoke) and hence the force exerted by the spoke on the mass just before the latter reaches the rim of the wheel.
>
> Assume that the rim is of negligible thickness (drawing not to scale).

[image]

My solution is:[image]

I have the final solution but my question is : Why is $\ddot \theta=0$?

Comment: Since this is your solution, you have made the assumption that $\ddot \theta=0$. Don't you know why you have done this? Or have you copied the solution from somewhere or someone?

Comment: I tried various methods to get the final solution of 53.3 Newtons. I got different answers due to this so i had to track back and make changes. By setting θ¨=0 i was able to get the answer but i dont know why. I want to know the theory behind this assumption

Comment: It is stated in the assumptions that $\omega = const.$

Comment: Please do not remove the content of your question - what did you try to achieve with that edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem states:

> As shown in Figure 7, a 2m diameter wheel rotates in the horizontal plane at a constant angular velocity ω= 7 rad/s.

So, ${\omega}=7\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}$ is given, which is all you need.

Since ${\omega}{\equiv}{\dot{\theta}}$,
$$\ddot{\theta}=\frac{\text{d}\dot{\theta}}{\text{d}t}=\frac{\text{d}{\omega}}{\text{d}t}=\frac{\text{d}{\left(7\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\right)}}{\text{d}t}=0.$$
In plain English, acceleration is zero because velocity is constant.

For a real-life analogy, think about driving a car.  If your car's going the same speed, then its acceleration is zero.  This is the same thing, except it's rotational speed is constant such that rotational acceleration is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have not been given the mass of the wheel, I think we must assume that it is much greater than that of the slider. We can then assume that the angular velocity $\dot \theta$ of the wheel is constant. (The question actually says that it is constant.) Therefore $\ddot\theta=\frac{d\dot\theta}{dt}=0$.